# python pyzipcode library check if zip code is missing

Tags: python, zipcode

I have a dataframe called dfZ with a zip code column and a value column. I am using the zip code and the 'pyzipcode' library to lookup city, state, latitude longitude etc.

The code below works great when the zip code exists in the library,

```
 import pyzipcode
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
zipDB = ZipCodeDatabase()
   
dfZ['State'] = dfZ['Zip'].apply(lambda x:zipDB[int(x)].state)
dfZ['LAT'] = dfZ['Zip'].apply(lambda x:zipDB[int(x)].latitude)
dfZ['LNG'] = dfZ['Zip'].apply(lambda x:zipDB[int(x)].longitude)
```

But say for example, if the zip code is 727, this does not exist in the library and throws out an error

I tried to modify the code with an if function to check if it is null but that isn't recognized.

```
pd.isnull(zipDB[727])
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPwaU.png)

edit text of error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-71-08eb3623e336> in <module>
----> 1 pd.isnull(zipDB[727])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzipcode\__init__.py in __getitem__(self, zipcode)
    179         data = self.get(str(zipcode).zfill(5))
    180         if data is None:
--> 181             raise KeyError(f"Couldn't find zipcode: '{zipcode}'")
    182         else:
    183             return data
KeyError: "Couldn't find zipcode: '727'"
```

Is there a way to write the code so that if it comes across an unknown zip code, it leaves them as Nan

Comment: Show the full error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Sure. added the text of the error message

Comment: You can replace the lambdas with normal functions which can catch the thrown exception and return something useful. You can also use "zipDB.get(727)" which will return "None" (or another default value if you specify one.